# This code is in an infinite loop and was wondering how to fix it

Tags: c++

```
for(num <= num2; num++;)
{
    for (i = 1; i <= num; i++)

        if(num % i == 0)

        prime++;
    cout << "There are "<< prime <<" prime numbers in the given range." << endl;
}
```

It seems to me that this should be right or I'm just overlooking some small detail. But when I output it keeps going.

Comment: You have the `num++` in the wrong place. It needs to read `for(;num <= num2; num++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong. For loop has 3 statements.

```
1) initialization. We can leave this blank if not required.
2) Condition
3) modification of variables.
```

your outer loop is missing first statement. So num <= num2 is getting treated as first statement.

It should be

```
for(;num <= num2; num++)
```

Comment: Thanks so much to you all it makes sense now. I was wondering how to make the first statement even though I already initialized it.

Answer (score 1):

`for(num <= num2; num++;)` this is the problem `for(init; condition; increment)` but your condition is `num++` now.

Answer (score 1):

You have a semi-colon after num++ on the first line. 
Should be `for(;num <= num2; num++)`